# mpdf orientation issue in php

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using **mpdf** for converting HTML to pdf file. I have tried following code for changing page orientation(Landscape of A5). But none of it working. I have also visited many solutions on stackoverflow,But it is not working for me.Please anyone suggest me whats wrong with these codes.

Thanks in advance

1:

```
include('MPDF57/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF($mode='',array(148,210),$default_font_size=0,$default_font='',$mgl=0,$mgr=0,$mgt=0,$mgb=0,$mgh=0,$mgf=0, $orientation='L');
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);

$text="
<table width='100%' border='1'><tr><td>sno</td><td>name</td></tr><tbody><tr><td style='width:10px;'>1</td><td>test</td></tr></tbody></table>";

$mpdf->WriteHTML($text);
$mpdf->Output();
```

2:

```
include('MPDF57/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF();

$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
//include inline css for changing orintation to landscape
$text="
<table style='sheet-size:5.8in 8.3in;size:landscape ' width='100%' border='1'><tr><td>sno</td><td>name</td></tr><tbody><tr><td style='width:10px;'>1</td><td>test</td></tr></tbody></table>";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($text);
$mpdf->Output();
```

3:

```
include('MPDF57/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF();

$mpdf->AddPage('c','A5-L');
$mpdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
//include inline css for changing orintation to landscape
$text="
<table  width='100%' border='1'><tr><td>sno</td><td>name</td></tr><tbody><tr><td style='width:10px;'>1</td><td>test</td></tr></tbody></table>";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($text);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A5','','',42,15,57,57,20,17);
$mpdf->AddPage('L'); try this

Comment: Thanks for ans..But it is not working for moziila browser...any solution please..